Numpy vectorize with if-statement: inconsistent with order of elements
Using the following two simple functions:
def x(t):
    return 0 if t < 0 else 1

def h(t):
    return 0 if t < 0 else np.exp(-t)

after applying x = np.vectorize(x) and h = np.vectorize(h) the first behaves as expected, with the output being independent of the order of the elements in the input array:
x(np.array([-1,0,1,2])) -> array([0, 1, 1, 1])
x(np.array([0,1,2,-1])) -> array([1, 1, 1, 0])

For the second function, I get different results if the values smaller zero are evaluated as first or as last elements...
h(np.array([-1,0,1,2])) -> array([0, 1, 0, 0])
h(np.array([0,1,2,-1])) -> array([1., 0.3678, 0.1353, 0.])

Is this a bug?

After some digging, it turns out that this is the expected behaviour. If the output data type is not specified, vectorize determines it from the first element. For the x-function, the output type is always int. For the h function, if -1 is provided as input, the output type determine as int, and the following non-integer values are cast to int.
This can be simply fixed by forcing the output type to be float, e.g. implicitly via the return value
def h(t):
    return 0. if t < 0 else np.exp(-t)

(note the "." after the 0), or explicitly via the otype argument to vectorize
h = np.vectorize(h, otypes=[float])


While that is the fix for np.vectorize, you should generally avoid using that function since it's slow. You can rewrite your code using np.where, which will be much faster for large arrays.

Or use masking instead.
